# Dual of quadratically-constrained quadratic program (QCQP) with second order cone constraints

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, qcqp, second-order-cone-programming

How to derive the dual of a quadratically-constrained quadratic program (QCQP) with second order cone constraint?
Here is the optimization problem I want to handle:

$$
\begin{array}{rl}\min_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}&\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{{T}}\mathbf{P}_0\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{q}_0^{{T}}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{r}_0\\ 
\text{s.t.}&\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{f}\\
&\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{D}\mathbf{y}\le\mathbf{g}\\
&\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{{T}}{\mathbf{P}}_{i}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{q}_{{i}}^{{T}}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{r}_{{i}}\leq0,{i}=1,\ldots,k\\
& \left\|\mathbf{S}_{i}\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{t}_{i}\right\|_2\leq\mathbf{u}_{i}^{T}\mathbf{y}+{v}_{i},{i}=1,\ldots,l\end{array}
$$
where $\mathbf P_0,\ldots,\mathbf P_m$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n, \mathbf y \in \mathbb R^m$ is the optimization variable. The optimization variables are separated into $ \mathbf x$ and $ \mathbf y$ as they follow different constraints.

In my setting, $\mathbf P_0,\ldots,\mathbf P_m$ are all positive semidefinite and thus the problem is convex. I wanna ask:

1. What is the dual of this problem?
2. How to ensure strong duality?